# Removing JavaScript behavior

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I need to remove the JavaScript behavior that I set on a `div`.
First, I set the CSS (it's an simple example) :

```
#redBloc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ad3232;
}

#redBloc:hover {
  background-color: #3270ad;
}
```

Okay, for some reasons I need to override the behavior when the mouse is over my div.

```
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');
redBloc.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

It works like I want.
But later in my process, I need to reset the JavaScript behavior, to retrieve the behavior written in my CSS file.

How can I do this ?

Thank you

### **EDIT**

I didn't need to override the behavior on the `onmouseleave` event, but later in my code, by the press of a button "disable behavior" for example.

That was solved by the solution of @T.J.Crowder.

Thank you all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean you want to remove the specific background color so that the one from CSS can show through again (rather than "behavior").

If so, assign `""` to it:

```
theElement.style.backgroundColor = "";
```

---

If you really *do* mean behavior and you don't want that mouseover handler to fire anymore, since you've used `onmouseover` to assign it, you can remove it by assigning `null`:

```
theElement.onmouseover = null;
```

Comment: Ok @T.J. Crowder, great ! I tried with `backgroundColor = "";` but the `onmouseover` event was still present.

With `onmouseover = null`, it works perfectly ! 

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the style attribute by running the this code

```
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');
redBloc.removeAttribute('style')
```

You can have functionality on `onmouseleave`

```
redBloc.onmouseleave = function(){
   this.removeAttribute('style');
}
```

Comment: Of course, this removes **all** inline styling, not just the background color. (It's fine if it's the only thing, but...)

Answer (score 0):

Make your element `null` on `mouseout`, like:

```
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');

redBloc.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};

redBloc.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '';
};
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');

redBloc.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};

redBloc.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '';
};
```

```css
#redBloc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ad3232;
}

#redBloc:hover {
  background-color: #3270ad;
}
```

```html
<div id="redBloc"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the effect when user leaves your element using `onmouseleave` & `null` the style attribute:

```js
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');
redBloc.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
redBloc.onmouseleave = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "";
};
```

```html
<span id="redBloc">Hover me &amp; leave me!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to give redBloc the style with id #redBloc defined in Your css ... What You can do is create a css class and put all the styles in it that you want to apply on redBloc

```
.redBloc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ad3232;
}
```

then in your javascript you can add this class to redBloc on mouseover

```
var redBloc = document.getElementById('redBloc');
redBloc.onmouseover = function() {
  this.className += " redBloc";

};
```

and this will add those styles defined in redBloc css class on your redBloc div. Hope this helps !